# Python can't infer static type of subclass when using a handler factory

Tags: python, class, types, subclass, factory

I would like to use a general `HandlerFactory` class like the one described [here](https://medium.com/@angusyuen/writing-maintainable-pythonic-code-metaprogramming-with-decorators-2fc2f1d358db) (see **Solution 2: Metaprogramming**).

Let me use an example:

Suppose we have the following classes:

```
class Person:
    name: str

@PersonHandlerFactory.register
class Mark(Person):
    name = "Mark"
    job = "scientist"

@PersonHandlerFactory.register
class Charles(Person):
    name = "Charles"
    hobby = "football"
```

You may have noticed that the subclasses contain a decorator. This decorator is used to register these classes into the following `PersonHandlerFactory` class, which returns a specific class given the person name:

```
from typing import Dict, Type

class PersonHandlerFactory:
    handlers: Dict[str, Type[Person]] = {}

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, handler_cls: Type[Person]):
        cls.handlers[handler_cls.name] = handler_cls
        return handler_cls

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, name: str):
        return cls.handlers[name]
```

As you can see, I used the type `Type[Person]`, because I want this method to be used for any subclass of `Person`.

But somehow Python interprets the static type of an instance of any subclass as the class `Parent`:

```
mark = Mark()  # Static type of 'mark' is 'Person' :S
print(mark.job)  # Python can't find the type of 'job'
```

I don't want to change `Type[Person]` for `Mark | Charles` because the class `PersonHandlerFactory` should not know about the subclasses of `Person`.

Comment: Why don't you define `age` on your Parent abstract class?

Comment: The idea is that the subclasses may have attributes that the parent class doesn't have. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a bound [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar), this allows the correct subclass to be inferred.

```
from typing import Dict, Type, TypeVar


class Person:
    name: str


T = TypeVar("T", bound=Person)


class PersonHandlerFactory:
    handlers: Dict[str, Type[Person]] = {}

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, handler_cls: Type[T]) -> Type[T]:
        cls.handlers[handler_cls.name] = handler_cls
        return handler_cls

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, name: str):
        return cls.handlers[name]


@PersonHandlerFactory.register
class Mark(Person):
    name = "Mark"
    job = "scientist"


mark = Mark()  # Static type of 'mark' is 'Mark' :)
```

The class returned by `PersonHandlerFactory.get` will however always be inferred as `Type[Person]`